# azure multiple public ip for a vm

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I want to have three public ip addresses for my VM in azure. I got one when I created the VM and now I want to assign two reserved ip addresses to my VM. I was able to create the reserved ip address but not sure how to assign them to existing VM or assign multiple to a new VM. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

In Azure, a Load Balancer is required in order to direct traffic from multiple VIP addresses to a single (or multiple) VMs.

If, for example, you want a single VM to host multiple websites, all of which need to be accessible externally via port 443, you'd need three VIP addresses assigned to the Load Balancer, with a NAT on each at least two of the VIPs; i.e.

1. Site a: Incoming 443-443 to VM
2. Site b: Incoming 443-444 to VM
3. Site c: Incoming 443-445 to VM

All the traffic from the Load Balancer could then be routed to one VM, where you'd direct traffic on each incoming port to the required website based.  This MS article explains it really well: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/load-balancer-multivip/

Reserved IP addresses are a way of ensuring that your VIP is no longer dynamic, which they are by default.  The following article explains it well, including how to take an existing Cloud Service's currently-running dynamic VIP and making it static (Reserved): https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/

Answer (score 1):

An Azure VM can have two public IP addresses - one is the VIP of the cloud service containing the VM (as long as there are endpoints configured for the VM) and the other is the [PIP](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-instance-level-public-ip/) (or public instance IP address) associated with the VM. A reserved IP address is an orthogonal concept to VIPs and PIPs and its use is documented [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/). I did a post on [VIPs, DIPs and PIPs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cloud_solution_architect/archive/2014/11/08/vips-dips-and-pips-in-microsoft-azure.aspx) that you may find helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I see we can have one VIP and one PIP for a VM. but looks like PIP changes on restart which doesn't meet our needs.